# Passing ls command to a for loop breaks when trying to use command line arguments

Tags: bash

Im writing a simple script to list all files in a directory and whether each file is in fact a file or if it is a directory. If it is a directory then it outputs how many files are in the directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

for filename in $(ls) 
do
   if [ -f "$filename" ]
   then
      printf "$filename - file\n"
   fi
   if [ -d "$filename" ]
   then
      count=$(ls "$filename" | wc -l)
      printf "$filename - directory $count files\n"
   fi
done
```

This works perfectly fine. But if I try to pass a command line argument (directory name) to ls then the script doesn't work. Does anyone know what causes this to break. Example below.

```
#!/bin/bash

for filename in $(ls $1) 
do
   if [ -f "$filename" ]
   then
      printf "$filename - file\n"
   fi
   if [ -d "$filename" ]
   then
      count=$(ls "$filename" | wc -l)
      printf "$filename - directory $count files\n"
   fi
done
```

Comment: If you are relatively _new_ to shell scripting, the idea of parsing `ls` is really wrong. See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  `ls` separates filenames with newlines. This is fine until you have a file with a newline in its name on which case it would break them as separate words.

Best way would be to use glob expansion to loop through the contents of a folder and apply your logic. For example in the logic below `*` and `*/` expands to the list of files and directory names in the current folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$filename` exists in `directory/$filename`. And you are check `$filename` in current (`./`) directory.

You should check against `directory/$filename`

```
if [ -z $1 ]; then
    echo USAGE: basename $0 directory
    exit
else
    directory=$1
fi

...
for ...
    if [ -f "$directory/$filename" ]; then
    ...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are passing directory as argument you shouldn't check files $filename but $1/$filename.

If you are sure that there will always be an argument you should use something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

for filename in $(ls "$1") 
do
   if [ -f "$1/$filename" ]
   then
      printf "$1/$filename - file\n"
   fi
   if [ -d "$1/$filename" ]
   then
      count=$(ls "$1/$filename" | wc -l)
      printf "$1/$filename - directory $count files\n"
  fi
done
```

If dirname as argument is optional you should check if there is argument and process as you want. My suggestion:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z ${1+x} ];
then
   echo "No argument";
else
   echo "There is argument";
   cd $1;
fi

for filename in $(ls) 
do
   if [ -f "$filename" ]
   then
      printf "$filename - file\n"
   fi
   if [ -d "$filename" ]
   then
      count=$(ls "$filename" | wc -l)
      printf "$filename - directory $count files\n"
   fi
done
```